# Access jQuery data from iframe element

Tags: jquery, iframe

Lets say I have a page on the **same domain** that I put inside an iframe. In the iframe, I have added data to an element, something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

Script

```
$('#data')
    .data('test1', 'this is test data 1')
    .data('test2', ['John', 'Smith'])
    .data('test3', {
        alert1: function() {
            $('#data').append('test3: successful<br>');
        }
    })
```

Now once this page is in an iframe, I know I can access the element as follows:

```
$('#frame').contents().find('#data');
```

But when I try to get the data from that element, it's always undefined.

```
$('#frame').contents().find('#data').data('test1'); // shows up as undefined
```

I know jQuery stores `data()` internally in a `cache` object, but I don't know how to access it from outside that document. I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/c5JeU/1/) to display my problem. Click the "Get Frame Data" button to see the results.

I would appreciate any input :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to get the cache element from *that* window's jQuery object, like this:

```
var windowjQuery = $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.$;
var f = $('#frame').contents().find('#data');
```

Then to get data, use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), like this:

```
windowjQuery.data(f[0], 'test1')
```

[You can test out your updated/working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c5JeU/2/).

---

What this is really accessing is:

```
var key = f[0][frame.contentWindow.$.expando];
var dataItem = frame.contentWindow.$.cache[key]["dataKey"];
```

Comment: @NickCraver you saved my day Captain !

Comment: Thanks for saving my day @NickCraver!

Comment: Thanks! Finally I got working solution. Only this way I was able to change data in iframe and then access it from iframe,

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried this, but I'm pretty certain you need to talk to the iframe's `$` object instead of your document's one to access that object's internal data storage. Not 100% sure how to do that - maybe something like

```
$('#frame').contents().jQuery.find("#data").data("test")
```

(wild guess)

What would work for sure is a function inside the iframe document that fetches the data, and returns it to you. But that's much less elegant than fetching it directly, of course.

Comment: There is not `jQuery` object under `contents()`, you will need to get it using `window.frames['myFrame'].contentWindow.jQuery`