# How to get the text within an text field which is inside an iframe if cross domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which I have taken one text field and also called an iframe inside it and in that iframe there is a text field for `Name`. I want to show that `Name` into my forms text field on key-up using JavaScript/jQuery. I mean as well as I have entered something into the `Name` text field it will show into my input field.
[image: See the attached image I want to display name from iframe in <code>Name</code> input field within form]

I am calling the iframe from another domain.I have used below code

```
<script> 
var iframe = document.getElementById('progressive');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var usernameTextBox = innerDoc.getElementById('ApplicantInfo1_FirstName');
usernameTextBox.focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var windowjQuery = $('#progressive')[0].contentWindow.$;
var f = $('#progressive').contents().find('#ApplicantInfo1_FirstName');
```

**UPDATE:**

You can read more on this topic in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101457/access-jquery-data-from-iframe-element), bec. I don't have possibility to setup environment for testing this particular case now.

The point is that, that you should call the `<iframe>` *jQuery* object (`$`), not of your parent page.

Comment: I am getting 
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: file:///C:/Users/monika.m/Desktop/iframe.html
Line: 30
Source Code:
var windowjQuery = $('#progressive')[0].contentWindow.$;

Answer (score 1):

In your parent page, do you control the domain name? If so, create a sub-domain. Let's say your parent page is called example.com, then create a subdomain iframe.example.com

In your parent page, you need then just set

```
document.domain = "example.com";
```

The subdomain with then be considered a safe domain and you will be allowed to talk between the 2 pages.

There is a more extensive description of this here:
[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure if this works in cross domain, but you might want to check out [jQuery .bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Here is an example for .bind()

```
$('#progressive').load(function() {
  $(this)
    .contents()
    .find('#ApplicantInfo1_FirstName')
    .bind('keydown', function() {
        //  do stuff
    });
});
```

More / better details [here on W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_bind.asp) and a live demo [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_bind_map). But those are not cross domain. Also more examples [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/bind/).

Otherwise, here is an example on how to access the javascript in a child iframe from the parent:

```
document.getElementById('ApplicantInfo1_FirstName').contentWindow.yourfunction()
```