# Reading <input> values from an iframe and sending it to another as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How should I read  values from iframe1 and send it to iframe2 as HTML?  Either JavaScript or jQuery is acceptable - it does not matter.  I'm new to javascript.  I already found code like the one below, maybe this will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getIframeText() {
            var iframe0 = document.getElementById("iframe0");
            var iframe0document=iframe0.contentDocument||iframe0.contentWindow.document;
            var inputIframe = iframe0document.getElementById("frame_text");
            alert(inputIframe.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="getIframeText()">get iframe text</button>
        <iframe id="iframe0"  src="test.html" >
        <input type=text id="parent_text">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are both iframes on your domain? If not need to read up on `same origin policy`... if so, why use iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c5JeU/2/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var fjq = $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.$;
    var f = $('#frame').contents().find('#data');

    f.append( '----------<br>');
    f.append( 'test1: ' + fjq.data(f[0], 'test1') + '<br>test2: ' + fjq.data(f[0], 'test2')  + '<br>' );
    f.append( 'test3: ' + typeof (fjq.data(f[0], 'test3')) + '<br>' );

})
```

I found it on: [Access jQuery data from iframe element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101457/access-jquery-data-from-iframe-element)