# How to access the options of a kendo grid inside an iframe from outside?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am working in a web application using kendo grid.I've an iframe which contains kendo grid and need to access the kendo options from outside using jquery.

Yeah I tried to access the element using below code

Iframe.contentWindow.find....this code returns the element but when I try to extend this to kendo element (element.data("kendoGrid") ) it shows undefined.Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to find the element using the `iframe.contentWindow` (which is right), but you didn't use the jQuery object of the iframe instead of the main window jQuery object.

You can access it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101551/2300466):

```
var framejQuery = $('#frameID')[0].contentWindow.$;
var element = $('#frameID').contents().find('#gridID')[0];
var grid = framejQuery.data(element, 'kendoGrid');         // Here's your grid object
```

Comment: this does not work for me.  var grid contains the document not the kendoGrid.

Comment: @StevenT.Cramer check how your code is different from this working example http://dojo.telerik.com/ugusa

Comment: Thank you for working example.  I figured out my mistake.